# Update Usage File in Microsoft Recommendations

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am using Microsoft Recommendations API in Java 8 and following the steps from [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f30d77eda5650db055a3d9)

```
Created a Model 
Uploaded Catalog File 
Uploaded Usage File 
Triggered a build 
Got the Recommendations
```

I want to update my usage file but cannot find any API. However there is an API for updating the Catalog File.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the API reference here:
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f30d77eda5650db055a3db

You can replace the usage file:

1. list the files uploaded - https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/577ec1847270320f24da25af
2. delete a file - https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/577ec1847270320f24da25b3
3. re-upload a new file - https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f316efeda5650db055a3e2